# keeping list view item highlighted

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, android-listfragment

I am working on the messaging app , when the message received it is updated in the list and I want to keep list view item highlighted all until they are clicked by the user in order to show the user that these are his new messages.Every time the message is received it is updated in the position 0 of the list view, and I want to highlight 0 position of the list view ,I am using :

```
adapter.insert(message, 0);
    ArrayAdapter<Message> adap = new ArrayAdapter<Message>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1) { 
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View itemView = super.getView(0, convertView, parent);
                 itemView.setBackgroundColor(0xA0FF8000); // orange
              return itemView;
        }
    };
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

My app give me error when the message is received:

```
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=soft.b.peopleassist flg=0x10 (has extras) } in soft.b.peopleassist.Receive$1@41cc2b50
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:795)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5000)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-26 14:48:20.891: E/AndroidRuntime(29012):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
```

Please help !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should not call the getView() method and thats why its throwing the error.
It seems like you havent set the new adapter to the list..!

Comment: Can you post your all relevant code.I give a try on my machine

Comment: its a hell lot of code , and one more thing the list is defined in the fragment.

Comment: can you just tell me how to highlight the list view item exactly/

Comment: but atleast post your activity code so i can understand what is happening